# how can i set success alert at middle of the page?

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, alert

in my application when user update or insert any data that time if return value is 1 then it displays a bootstrap success alert. but it appears at the end of the page and i want it at middle of the page or at the div box footer. here is my code for that page.

ClassConnection.php :

```
<?php

 class connection
 {

 Public $ServerName="localhost";
 Public $ServerUser="root";
 Public $ServerPassword="";
 Public $DatabaseName="taksicab";


public $mycon=" ";
public $rs = " " ;
public $sql= " ";
public $myquery = " ";
    function open_connection()
    {
      $con=mysql_connect($this->ServerName, $this->ServerUser, $this->ServerPassword);

      if(!$con)
      {
         die("Error in connection .......");
      }

      else
      {
            $this->mycon=$con;
            return $this->mycon;
      }
   }

   function SelectDB()
   {
      mysql_select_db($this->DatabaseName);
   }


    //DBOperations

     function DBOperation ($mTable,$mFields,$mValues,$mOperation)
     {
        $mSQL="";
        $mStr="";

    $tFields = explode(",",$mFields);
    $tValues = explode(",",$mValues);


    if($mOperation == "Insert")
    {

        $mSQL = "Insert into " . $mTable . "( " . $mFields . ") values ( " . $mValues . ")";
        $query = mysql_query($mSQL);




    }


    else if($mOperation == "Update")
    {

                for($i=0; $i<count($tFields); $i++)
                {

                    if($i== (count($tFields)-1))
                    {

                        $mStr = $mStr . " " . $tFields[$i] . " = " . $tValues[$i];
                    }

                    else
                    {       
                        $mStr=$mStr . " " . $tFields[$i] . " = " . $tValues[$i] . " , ";
                    }

                }

        $mSQL = "Update " . $mTable . " set " . $mStr . " Where " . $tFields[0] . " = " . $tValues[0];
        $query = mysql_query($mSQL);


    }

    else if($mOperation == "Delete")
    {

        $mSQL = "Delete from " . $mTable . " Where " . $tFields[0] . " = " . $tValues[0];
    }


   // echo $mSQL;

$this->myquery = $query ;
    return $this->myquery;



}

 }

 ?>
```

Block_User.php

```
   <?php
      include("ClassConnection.php");

    $mcon=new connection();

   $mcon->open_connection();
    $mcon->SelectDB();



   ?>


   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <title>Block User | Admin Taksi</title>
       <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
           <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-      scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
     <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <!-- Ionicons -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
   <!-- Theme style -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">

     <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media   queries -->
     <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js">       </script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
   </head>
    <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
     <div class="wrapper">

     <!-- Main Header -->
      <header class="main-header">

  <!-- Logo -->
  <a href="index2.html" class="logo">
  <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
  <span class="logo-mini"><b>A</b>LT</span>
    <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
   <span class="logo-lg"><b>Admin</b>&nbsp;Taksi</span>
  </a>

   <!-- Header Navbar -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
  <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  </a>
  <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
  <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <!-- User Account Menu -->
      <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
        <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
          <img src="../dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
          <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
          <span class="hidden-xs">Ravi Barot</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- The user image in the menu -->
          <li class="user-header">
            <img src="../dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

            <p>
              Ravi Barot - Web Developer
              <small>Tarinee since May. 2016</small>
            </p>
          </li>
          <!-- Menu Body -->
          <li class="user-body">

            <!-- /.row -->
          </li>
          <!-- Menu Footer-->
          <li class="user-footer">

            <div class="pull-right">
              <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
   </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
    <aside class="main-sidebar">

<!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
<section class="sidebar">

  <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
  <div class="user-panel">
    <div class="pull-left image">
      <img src="../dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
    </div>

    <div class="pull-left info">
      <p>Ravi Barot</p>
      <!-- Status -->

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- search form (Optional) -->
  <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- /.search form -->

  <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
  <ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="header">Main Menu</li>
    <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
    <li>
    <a href="dashboard.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> 
    <span>Dashboard</span>
    </a>
    </li>




    <li class="treeview">
      <li class="active">
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-users"></i> 
     <span>Manage Users</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li class="active">
    <a href="block_user.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Block User
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="obsulate_user.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Obsulate User
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>


  <li class="treeview"> 
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-cab"></i> 
    <span>Manage Cabs</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li>
    <a href="add_cab.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Add Cab
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="obsulate_cab.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Obsulate Cab
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="treeview"> 
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> 
    <span>Manage Driver</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li>
    <a href="add_driver.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Add Driver
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="obsulate_driver.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Obsulate Driver
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="treeview"> 
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-star-half-full"></i> 
    <span>Manage Cab Category</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li>
    <a href="add_cab_category.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Add Cab Category
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="obsulate_cab_category.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Obsulate Cab Category
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="treeview"> 
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-road"></i> 
    <span>Manage Route</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li>
    <a href="add_source_place.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Add Source Place
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="obsulate_source_place.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Obsulate Source Place
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="add_desti_place.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Add Destination Place
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="obsulate_desti_place.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Obsulate Destination Place
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="treeview"> 
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-h"></i> 
    <span>Manage Route Distance</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li>
    <a href="add_distance.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Add Route Distance
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="update_distance.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Update Route Distance
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="treeview"> 
    <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-rupee"></i> 
    <span>Manage Fare</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li>
    <a href="add_new_fair.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Add New Fare
    </a>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="obsulate_fair.php">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> 
    Obsulate Current Fare
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>

     </ul>
     <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
    </aside>

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
     <div class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
    <h1>Manage User

  </h1>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Level</a></li>
    <li class="active">Here</li>
  </ol>
</section>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">

  <!-- Your Page Content Here -->

  <div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Block User</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <!-- form start -->
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Email ID</label>

              <div class="col-xs-5">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" name="user_email">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Block Reason </label>

              <div class="col-xs-5">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Reason for Blocking" name="block_reason">
              </div>
            </div>



              <!-- select -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="form-control" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Block Peroid</label>
              <div class="col-xs-5">
                  <select class="form-control" name="block_period">
                      <option value="1 week">1 Week</option>
                      <option value="1 month">1 Month</option>
                      <option value="permenent">Permenent</option>

              </select>
            </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="box-footer">

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left" name="block_user">Block User</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-footer -->

        </form>
      </div>

      </section>
      <!-- /.content -->
      </div>
       <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

   <!-- Main Footer -->
   <footer class="main-footer">
  <!-- To the right -->
  <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">All rights reserved
  </div><strong>Copyright &copy; 2016 Parshwa Technology</strong> 
   </footer>

   <!-- Control Sidebar -->
   <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
   <!-- Create the tabs -->
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified control-sidebar-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#control-sidebar-home-tab" data-toggle="tab">           <i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#control-sidebar-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa   fa-gears"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <!-- Home tab content -->
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="control-sidebar-home-tab">
    <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Recent Activity</h3>
    <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="javascript::;">
          <i class="menu-icon fa fa-birthday-cake bg-red"></i>

          <div class="menu-info">
            <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Langdon's Birthday</h4>

            <p>Will be 23 on April 24th</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

    <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Tasks Progress</h3>
    <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="javascript::;">
          <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
            Custom Template Design
            <span class="label label-danger pull-right">70%</span>
          </h4>

          <div class="progress progress-xxs">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 70%"></div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.tab-pane -->
  <!-- Stats tab content -->
  <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-stats-tab">Stats Tab Content</div>
  <!-- /.tab-pane -->
  <!-- Settings tab content -->
  <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
    <form method="post">
      <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">General Settings</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
          Report panel usage
          <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
        </label>

        <p>
          Some information about this general settings option
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.form-group -->
      </form>
     </div>
     <!-- /.tab-pane -->
    </div>
    </aside>
    <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
    <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
   immediately after the control sidebar -->
   <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
   </div>
   <!-- ./wrapper -->

     <!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->

   <!-- jQuery 2.2.0 --> 
     <script src="../plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
   <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!-- AdminLTE App -->
   <script src="../dist/js/app.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Optionally, you can add Slimscroll and FastClick plugins.
       Both of these plugins are recommended to enhance the
   user experience. Slimscroll is required when using the
    fixed layout. -->
   </body>
   </html>
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST["block_user"]))
    {



  $mTable = "blocked_user_master";
  $mFields = "User_Email,Block_Reason,Block_Period";
  $mValues = "'".$_POST['user_email']. "','" . $_POST['block_reason'] . "','" . $_POST['block_period'] . "'";
  $mOperation = "Insert";

 $r = $mcon->DBOperation($mTable,$mFields,$mValues,$mOperation);

$mTable1 = "user_master";
$mFields1 = "User_Email,Blocked";
$mValues1 = "'" . $_POST['user_email'] ."',1";

 $mOperation1 = "Update";

 $r1 = $mcon->DBOperation($mTable1,$mFields1,$mValues1,$mOperation1);

// echo $r.$r1; 
if($r1 && $r == 1)
{

echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible col-xs-5'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
            <h4><i class='icon fa fa-check'></i> Alert!</h4>
            Success... 
         </div> ";
  }


}

?>
```

Comment: Your code is using `mysql_` functions that have been deprecated for years and now [no longer exist in the latest PHP versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). On top of that, your code is very prone to an [SQL injection attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You should really upgrade your bookshelf or use the official documentation for learning PHP.

Comment: you are right my friend i will update it with mysqli or pdo but my actual problem wont fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with fancy javascript which will move div box with output message into wherever you like.

But that's only dirty hack, not the proper way to code.

The proper way is to divide operation and display (at least, MVC is even better).
This way you can set some variable indicating name was changes and generate a page from template based on that variable (ie with success msg set on top of page if there is one).

Please don't make your own template engine. Use some existing ones instead (Savant is quite easy to learn).

**Edit:** 
Ok, I won't give you ready-to-use code, instead I will tell you how to do it the quick-but-dirty way:

1) create a div in which you want your message to appear, place it wherever you want it to be and give it some id (unique in page scope) ie:

```
<div id="resultMsg"></div>
```

2) later in your php code: instead of printing div with a message, print some javascript which will fill your resultMsg container with a message:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("resultMsg").innerHTML = "put your generated message here";</script>';
```

It's quick fix but don't get used to it. Instead learn how to do this the right way. You can start with https://github.com/phplucidframe/phplucidframe/wiki/Integration-of-Savant,-The-Simple-Template-System or use other templating system. It will save you many bigger problems than this one in future :)

Comment: but i don't have knowledge of mvc so can use please fix it within this code?

Comment: Thank You friend you complete my application and i will sure follow your suggestion. Thanks again dear :)